# Obtener los Following usando TwitterAPIExchange.php

Tags: php, twitter-api

Busco una manera de obtener los Following  usando la librería

> TwitterAPIExchange. php

E logrado mandar tweets usando esta librería de esta forma:

```
    require_once 'libs/twitteroauth.php';

            /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/ 
    // array de acceso
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => 'xxxx',
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => 'xxxx',
        'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxx',
        'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxx',
    );

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

// tipo de metodo
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$wp = array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

//tweet
$postfields = array('status' => 'Mi tweet enviado desde PHP');

// instancia de la conexion con twitter
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange ($settings);

// enviamos el tweet
$response = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->setPostfields($postfields)
                    ->performRequest(true,$wp),$assoc = TRUE);
```

Todo bien sin problemas mi pregunta es Como obtener la lista de User que sigo **(Following)** Usando esta librería

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo sería necesario:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

Asimismo, los parámetros opcionales que se puede enviar son (existen más):

- **count:** Por defecto 20 y máximo 200, número de usuarios por página a obtener
- **cursor:** Por defecto -1, sirve para navegar entre los resultados obtenidos (permite paginar los resultados obtenidos). Cada vez que hagas una consulta obtendrás también ***previous_cursor*** y ***next_cursor*** los cuales usarás para la navegaciones.

Ejemplo:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json';
$getfield = '?count=200&cursor=1333504313713126852'; // POR EJEMPLO
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

Recordar que `setGetfield` es opcional.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/)
- [GET friends/list](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list)
- [Using cursors to navigate collections](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring)

Comment: Gracias por el dato esta forma regresa los nombres o el id de la personas que sigo

Comment: Te trae la información pública relacionada a cada amigo, cuando ingreses a la referencia podrás ver la estructura JSON que retorna. Asimismo, puedes usar la [API Console](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console) para visualizar las opciones de retorno que te ofrece.

Comment: solo da 27 resultados existe una forma de obtener  mas resultados

Comment: Adicione datos adicionales a la respuesta. Trata de ayudarte con traductores para leer las referencias que te agrego.

Comment: Gracias por la información el código queda así $getfield = '?count=200&cursor=-1333504313713126852';  solo le agregue el **-** para que funcione